# Does "No more" by necessity imply there was some before?

Tags: meaning, comparatives, comparisons, degree-of-comparison

If I say "I have no more apples" do I have to have had some apples to begin with? Is there an instance where I could start with none and still say I had no more sensically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the first sentence, yes, and to the second, no.  No context in which I have ever heard this type of statement has supported the possibility of there having been no apples to begin with.

The basic reason I would infer for this is that we never use *[more](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/more)* per se to mean *more than nothing*. Hence, *more* always implies that there was at least one apple at the beginning.

There are two usages of *no more*.  You could be showing a full apple-barrel to a customer and telling him that you have *no more* apples [than what is in front of him], or you could be sold out for the day and be telling him that you have *no more* apples [than what you already sold].

Semantically, there is no reason why *no more* shouldn't mean *no more than nothing ever*; it's just that no one has ever used it that way, and if someone has never had an apple, and still has no apples, he would say *I have no apples*, not *I have no more apples*.

Comment: I fail to see the difference between your “two meanings.”

Comment: *No more* can mean *no more than this* (pointing at something), or it can mean *no more than what I've already gotten rid of*.  The second scenario is different in that *no more* indicates that you have none now.  The reason why I'm stressing this point is that it is easy to equivocate *no more [than what I no longer have]* with *no more [than nothing]*.  The former is a correct meaning of *no more*, while the latter is never used as a meaning of *no more*.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I would not describe that difference as “There are two meanings of _no more_,” but now I see the difference you are referring to.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion!  Based on what you just said, I decided to change *two meanings* to *two usages*.  Hope that helps!

Comment: How about a third meaning/usage? *I have no more desire to eat oysters than to catch ebola.*

Comment: The Mad Hatter would beg to disagree with this answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, general usage says "no more" implies there having been some apples at another point in time. If there never were any apples to begin with, one might instead say, "We don't have (sell) apples."

Answer (score 0):

This question has been linked to from https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333798/the-this-question-has-been-closed-message-is-misleading:

Regarding the sentence "This question has been closed - no more answers will be accepted." one person commented:

> Note: the word "more" is avoided because there may be no answers, and "more" implies at least one answer exists.

I think this is incorrect. The sentence implies that answers were at one point accepted, but not necessarily that there are any answers to the question.

Comment: While the intention here is doubtless 'Whether there have been 0, 17, or a million answers to date, answers will not be accepted from now on', this is not exactly what the given sentence conveys. The accepted meaning of 'No more answers will be will be accepted' is 'No further answers will be will be accepted' , which definitely demands that at least one answer has been proffered.